# How to make html5 "week" input type start on sunday

Tags: html

```
<input type="week" />
```

shows the highlighted starting week as Monday. Is there a way to make it show Sunday as the start of the week to prevent confusion?

Comment: Unless you're building a web-app for Chrome, You shouldn't use the `<input type="week" />` element, though it's not supported in Firefox and IE, which the majority of users use.

Comment: I think that has to do with the culture-specific implementation of the  browser, and that browsers will show different weeks in different countries. For more adjustable date-picker, you should check out date-picker plugins, such as [jQueryUI's](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: Here the complete doc : http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.week.html. Unfortunately I don't see nothing to change the starting day of the week.

Comment: I think you should add a `input[type=checkbox]` to solve that. Week `input` aim is to choose a week (from 1 to 52 or 53), but not a range of 7 days. For that, it's better to use an `input[type=date]` to choose the first day with a `list=datalistID` indicate a list of sundays

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible at this time. You can find the spec for the "week" input type here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.week.html

There is no mention of specifying the start day.

Answer (score 3):

The week concept in this context is based on the international ISO 8601 standard, according to which Monday is the first day of the week. This follows from the general definitions in the HTML 5 draft, but it also spells this out explicitly when describing the [week concept](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#concept-week): “A **week** consists of a week-year number and a week number representing a seven-day period starting on a Monday.”

So the value of the control unavoidably represents a week that starts on a Monday. Even though browsers have great liberties in implementing the user interfaces of controls, it would thus be grossly misleading if a browser showed weeks as starting on Sundays when implementing `type=week`. For other types of controls, not involving the selection of a week as input, browsers could conceivably show calendars with weeks starting on Sundays, if that applies to the locale being used.